Authenticated requests to OpenSearch service with Cognito user
I've got a AWS OpenSearch service configured with Cognito authentication for OpenSearch Dashboards
I followed the steps: created a user pool, identity pool, the roles, and new user. At the end I successfully logged in to the OpenSearch dashboard with the cognito user. So far so good. But now I want to use a client like Postman (or programmatically using fetch API) to login/authenticate and issue requests.
I acquired the AccessToken, IdToken, RefreshToken from Cognito. Then I tried firing a request to the OpenSearch domain with Authorization Bearer  but I got response 401 Unauthorized and the message Authentication finally failed
Has anyone succeded querying data from OpenSearch using clients like Postman or regular fetch API?
